# Increase Android ViewPager performance

Tags: android, performance, android-viewpager

I'm creating a android application with target on 2.2. I still want to use the ViewPager provided in the android.support-v4.jar.

I'm using a FragmentPagerAdapter in combination with Fragment to display content.
Each fragment contains a WebView, displaying some html data.

Scrolling a WebView up and down works great but the swiping between pages in the ViewPager behaves very jerky and not at all as smooth as scrolling the WebView.

Is there any way you can increase the scroll performance of the ViewPager, maybe something like ConvertView from BaseAdapter?

I'm guessing I could load the url in a background thread but from what I've heard that's not best practice.

Any suggestions would be great, thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I realized you could use the

```
viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(items.size());
```

to keep all items preloaded in memory and avoid the "freeze/laggy" performance while scrolling,.

Comment: Just a question, maybe an idiot question: wouldn't it be too much heavy the preloading of all the viewpager's items?

Comment: I mean, couldn't I get any error like OutOfMemory or similar?

Comment: You could, it all depends on how many items you will have and how "UI heavy" each view is. What I did to make sure this wouldn't happen was to hardcode the size of items to something a lot higher then what would be realistic for my application.

Comment: I understand.. I said these things because I'm starting an application which will surely have heavy images (high quality, blur, stuff like this) to load in each Fragment of the ViewPager.. But, I'll manage them as it needs to be done :)

Comment: This might be the worst solution I've come across. You do NOT want to load all pages in memory as UI is much more memory intensive that simply keeping a list of POJOs in memory. Rather, something else is causing your loading to be slow and probably consider evaluating how you're creating the UI. You might want to consider recycling pages instead.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider reusing the `Fragments` by providing some method to reuse existing fragments in the ViewPager and populate or refresh it's UI with the new data.